# Problem with line of code while making vanilla js slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I have watched a tutorial on making a vanilla JS slider, I've understood the whole code since it was pretty easy but 1 line of code doesn't make any sense to me, even if you remove that line of code the slider works perfectly fine, can you explain to me what it does since the one who made the video didn't explain what that line of code does.

the line of code which I don't understand, what does it do in the code?

```
 setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
```

And the whole JS code

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
const next = document.querySelector('#next');
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');
const auto = false; // Auto scroll
const intervalTime = 5000;
let slideInterval;

const nextSlide = () => {
  // Get current class
  const current = document.querySelector('.current');
  // Remove current class
  current.classList.remove('current');
  // Check for next slide
  if (current.nextElementSibling) {
    // Add current to next sibling
    current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current');
  } else {
    // Add current to start
    slides[0].classList.add('current');
  }
  setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
};

const prevSlide = () => {
  // Get current class
  const current = document.querySelector('.current');
  // Remove current class
  current.classList.remove('current');
  // Check for prev slide
  if (current.previousElementSibling) {
    // Add current to prev sibling
    current.previousElementSibling.classList.add('current');
  } else {
    // Add current to last
    slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('current');
  }
  setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
};

// Button events
next.addEventListener('click', e => {
  nextSlide();
  if (auto) {
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, intervalTime);
  }
});

prev.addEventListener('click', e => {
  prevSlide();
  if (auto) {
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, intervalTime);
  }
});

// Auto slide
if (auto) {
  // Run next slide at interval time
  slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, intervalTime);
}
```

And this is the link to the whole code.
https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/oVPBaa

Answer (score 0):

As it is a setTimeout, then this function call:

```
() => current.classList.remove('current');
```

happens on an entirely different execution context as the global context (by the way, if you emit the second parameter in a setTimeout, then that means that it happens in 0 milliseconds, although instantaneous, it still happens outside of the normal event loop given the nature of it being a setTimeout function)

So, I think Brad put it as a fail-safe proof that if you click the next or previous buttons spammingly, then the pointer to the current slide in which you have just skipped will always get the 'current' class remove from its classList.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's unnecssary in this case, but this is for the reason if `current.classList.remove('current')` won't be executed the code inside `setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));` will be executed last. This is just like an insurance. Look at the short theory:

```
console.log('One');
setTimeout(()=>console.log('Two'));
console.log('Three');

The console logs: One, Three, Two.
```

This happens because code inside setTimeout is sets to the callback queque and will be executed only if stack will be empty, because setTimeout is an async function. (setTimeout is a Web API function so, after being in the stack and before being in the callback queque will be pushed to the Web API box)